# Проверка на верное количество скобок [ { ( ) } ]

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Задача следующая, написать код, который проверяет, верно ли расставлены скобки в выражении т.е.

---

`("(5+5)/[4+4]*{2*2}" - True, "(3+[2*3)]" - False` .

---

Код я написал, честно говоря, показывать конечно стыдно, но увы, никто кроме Вас, меня умнее не сделает. Просьба - подскажите, как можно сделать из ЭТОГО, нормальный код? Сам по себе код работает.

---

```
def checkio(expression):
    list_backets = []

    for i in expression:
        if i == "[" or i == "]" or i == "(" or i == ")" or i == "{" or i == "}":
            list_backets.append(i) //создаю список нужных нам элементов

    if len(list_backets) == 0: //если нет элементов вовсе
        return True

    elif list_backets.count("[") == list_backets.count("]") and list_backets.count("(") == list_backets.count(")") and list_backets.count("{") == list_backets.count("}"):
      //если количество "(" равно количеству ")" и так далее...
        j = 0
        try:
            while j != range(len(list_backets)): //попытка найти в списке соседние скобки
                if list_backets[j] == "(" and list_backets[j+1] == ")":
                    list_backets.pop(j)
                    list_backets.pop(j)
                    j = 0
                elif list_backets[j] == "{" and list_backets[j+1] == "}":
                    list_backets.pop(j)
                    list_backets.pop(j)
                    j = 0
                elif list_backets[j] == "[" and list_backets[j+1] == "]":
                    list_backets.pop(j)
                    list_backets.pop(j)
                    j = 0
                else:
                    j += 1

        except:
            if (len(list_backets)) == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False

    else:
            return False
```

---

Выглядит стремно и неуклюже, если у Вас будет возможность и время, расскажите как сделать его более "красивым" с пояснениями.
Спасибо!

Comment: вам надо непременно самому это реализовать или вы готовы пользоваться уже написанными и отлаженными библиотеками?

Comment: Чтобы из этого сделать нормальный код, необходимо выбрать другой алгоритм решения.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Проверить правильно ли вложены скобки 〈 ( { } ) 〉в тексте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587694/23044)

Comment: для создания хорошего ответа в метке [tag:инспекция-кода], может пригодится [ответ @200_success♦ с codereview.SE](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/913/6143)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Используйте проверку правописания

```
list_backets -> brackets
```

Заодно имя типа (`list`) здесь не обязательно. `brackets` почти в каждой строчке используется и само по себе достаточно читаемо.

### Возвращайте булевы выражения напрямую

Вместо:

```
if (len(list_backets)) == 0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Можно писать просто:

```
return (not list_brackets)
```

пустые коллекции в Питоне рассматриваются `False` в булевом контексте

### Избегайте bare `except:`, которое ловит все типы исключений

Эта конструкция перехватывает даже `KeyboardInterrupt` (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>) и `SystemExit` (выход из скрипта, реализация `sys.exit()`)—это нежелательно. Ловите только те типы исключений, которые вы ожидаете, иначе вы можете проигнорировать ошибки во вводе или ошибки, вызванные багом в коде—неожиданные ошибки должны прекращать скрипт в данном случае.

В Питоне иногда позволительно использовать исключения для управлением потока кодом, но фактически использование следует ограничить случаями, когда это заметно упрощает код улучшает его читаемость, эффективность.

В коде в вопросе, использование перехвата исключений указывает на проблему с организацией цикла. Следует переорганизовать код, чтобы вообще исключить try/except в данном случае.

### Сравнение целого числа с `range()` это баг

Замените `j != range(len(list_backets))` на `j != len(brackets)`

### Избегайте управление переменной цикла в ручную. Обходите коллекции напрямую.

То есть вместо:

```
j = 0
while j != len(brackets):
    print(brackets[j])
    j += 1
```

Пишите:

```
for bracket in brackets:
    print(bracket)
```

Ваш алгоритм требует управления переменной цикла, что делает его менее понятным и (в данном случае) менее эффективным (выглядит как квадратичный алгоритм). Для сравнения, [вот линейный алгоритм, который обходит коллекцию напрямую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587696/23044).

### Используйте # вместо // для комментариев в Питоне

### Избегайте излишнего дублирования кода

Вместо:

```
i == "[" or i == "]" or i == "(" or i == ")" or i == "{" or i == "}"
```

Можно написать:

```
character in "[](){}"
```

В данном случае все скобки представлены одним символом. Чтобы поддерживать скобки из нескольких символов, можно в кортеж положить:

```
token in ('>>', '<<', ']', '[', '}', '{')
```

Вместо:

```
(list_backets.count("[") == list_backets.count("]")
 and list_backets.count("(") == list_backets.count(")")
 and list_backets.count("{") == list_backets.count("}"))
```

можно написать:

```
all(brackets.count(opening) == brackets.count(closing)
    for opening, closing in zip("[({", "])}"))
```

Небольшое повторение кода может быть полезно. В крайности впадать не следует. Смотрите по ситуации, какой код более понятен и легче изменять, не поломав, через полгода, когда детали забудутся.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
>             list_backets.pop(j)
>             list_backets.pop(j)
>             j = 0
> ```

Эти куски кода явно повторяются, поэтому нет смысла делать 3 разных if'а. Условия вполне можно записать через `or`.

> ```
> except:
>     if (len(list_backets)) == 0:
>         return True
>     else:
>         return False
> ```

Проверка на пустую строку уже была. Почему она тут второй раз? И почему вообще ожидается, что тут произойдёт исключение? Сто-то тут надо переделать, наверное.

> ```
>             list_backets.pop(j)
>             list_backets.pop(j)
> ```

Если я правильно понимаю, это удаление из середины списка? Да ещё и дважды (по разу на каждую скобку). Обычно это крайне неэффективно, хотя про питон сказать не могу.

> ```
>     list_backets.append(i) //создаю список нужных нам элементов
> ```

А зачем скобки в отдельном списке? Можно проходить по строке и сразу обрабатывать.

---

## Предлагаю такое решение:

Завести набор скобок (6 штук) и словарь из соответствий закрывающих скобок открывающим (закрывающая - ключ, открывающая - значение).

```
завести пустой стек

для каждого символа строки
  если он присутствует в наборе скобок
    если он отсутствует в словаре соответствий, т. е. это открывающая скобка
      добавить в стек этот символ
    иначе он закрывающая скобка
      если значение из словаря соответствий отличается от вершины стека
        return false
      иначе
        выкинуть последний элемент стека

return стек пуст
```

Comment: *"Почему она тут второй раз? "* потому что длина списка изменяется по ходу исполнения кода.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю наилучшим решением будет использование стека и постоянное удаление элементов в нем, если скобки открывающаяся и закрывающаяся совпадают, то они очищаются из стека и так до тех пор, пока он не окажется пустым.

```
def check(string):
    brackets_open = ('(', '[', '{', '<')
    brackets_closed = (')', ']', '}', '>')
    stack = []
    for i in string:
        if i in brackets_open:
            stack.append(i)
        if i in brackets_closed:    
            if len(stack) == 0:
                return False
            index = brackets_closed.index(i)
            open_bracket = brackets_open[index]
            if stack[-1] == open_bracket:
                stack = stack[:-1]  
            else: return False  
    return (not stack)
```

Применение очень простое:
создаем строки которые нужно проверить на правильность.

```
str1 = '[{([[[<>]]])(<>)(){}}]' 
str2 = ']()(){<>}[[()]]' 
str3 = '[(sjd),"2"],{2:3}, [<>]'
str4 = '{[[[[((()))]]<]>]}'
```

Затем применяем к ним функцию:

```
print(check(str1))  #True
print(check(str2))  #False
print(check(str3))  #True
print(check(str4))  #False
```

Comment: ответы к вопросам с меткой [tag:инспекция-кода] должны, что-то о коде в вопросе сказать (построчная критика или просто в целом обзор)¶ Если вы просто хотите решение опубликовать, не рассматривая код в вопросе, то есть другой вопрос: [Проверить правильно ли вложены скобки 〈 ( { \[ \] } ) 〉в тексте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587694/23044) (ваш код напоминает решение из принятого ответа там)

Answer (score 1):

Мне в голову пришло такое наглядное решение, без синтаксических деревьев или чего прочего. Представим, что каждая открывающаяся скобка - это элементарная частица. Закрывающаяся скобка - противоположная ей. Если строка валидная, то частицы должны аннигилировать. Если что-то осталось - строка неверна. Во время проверки скобки бросают в общую кучу и если вдруг они находят противоположную пару - все взрывается, ололо. По сути это перефразированное и менее производительное решение из верхнего ответа.

```
class ElectronPositronValidator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.op_brackets = ("(", "[", "{", "<")
        self.clos_brackets = (")", "]", "}", ">")
        self.opposite_brackets = {"(": ")",
                                  "[": "]",
                                  "{": "}",
                                  "<": ">"}
        self.bracket_dump = ""

    def _add_to_dump(self, bracket):
        self.bracket_dump = self.bracket_dump + bracket
        if bracket in self.clos_brackets:
            # Проверим на предмет аннигиляции две последние скобки
            if len(self.bracket_dump) >= 2 and \
               self.bracket_dump[-1] == self.opposite_brackets.get(self.bracket_dump[-2], None):
                self._annihilate()

    def _annihilate(self):
        self.bracket_dump = self.bracket_dump[:-2]

    def is_valid(self, target_string):
        self.bracket_dump = ''
        for char in target_string:
            if char in self.op_brackets or char in self.clos_brackets:
                self._add_to_dump(char)
        if self.bracket_dump:
            return False
        else:
            return True


validator = ElectronPositronValidator()
print(validator.is_valid("(5+5)/[4+4]*{2*2}"))
print(validator.is_valid("()()()()()()()()()()"))
print(validator.is_valid("([{<|>}])"))
print(validator.is_valid("3[||:||]Ɛ"))
print(validator.is_valid(""))

print(validator.is_valid("(3+[2*3)]"))
print(validator.is_valid("()()()()()()()()()("))
print(validator.is_valid("()[]{}<>}{"))
print(validator.is_valid("({{[[  >  ]]}})"))
print(validator.is_valid(">([])<"))
```

Comment: ответы к вопросам с меткой [tag:инспекция-кода] должны, что-то о коде в вопросе сказать (построчная критика или просто в целом обзор)¶ Если вы просто хотите решение опубликовать, не рассматривая код в вопросе, то есть другой вопрос: [Проверить правильно ли вложены скобки 〈 ( { \[ \] } ) 〉в тексте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587694/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Добра всем!
Случайно набрел на этот пост и вот что придумал:
1. Как минимум должно быть четное количество скобок - открыли\закрыли.
2. Использовать regex!

```
import re
exp = '{*08/)348+124[7{)7{/[){5[}506(}*178][]/-{71)]7[19{05{-{*)}7(5+2)54]43-*2+(*74]{44}){52{/{0]88{(})9}90}}50[)(*41{{8+)-/38/5/*({0(-28*21/8{+{*9*22-/269+44-[/)298043{40]75/-1[4[26(/4]3-{71-]{554}65*6{20558*6{*/32)-{6++*/92]+623{1-59+/749291)161)(((-21-+++[0138)3*3+]+3{[4)952})124/3]9/)]/2+})(-964}'
exp_mod = ''.join([el for el in exp if el in ('(',')','{','}','[',']')]) #убираем все кроме скобок
if len(exp_mod) % 2 != 0:
    print(False) #если нечетно количество - сразу в утиль
elif len(re.findall(r'\((?=[\]\}])|\[(?=[\)\}])|\{(?=[\)\]])', exp_mod)) > 0:
    print(False) #если после открытия сразу есть иное закрытие (например, после '{' идет ']')- тоже в утиль
else: # ищем соотв пары '()','[]','{}' и те же пары, только с 2, 4 и далее другими скобками м/у ними - ну тут напутано, можно и попроще
    pattern = r'\(\)|\[\]|\{\}|\(.{2}\)|\[.{2}\]|\{.{2}\}|\(.{4}\)|\[.{4}\]|\{.{4}\}|\(.{' + str(len(exp_mod)-4) + '}\)|\[.{' + str(len(exp_mod)-4) + '}\]|\{.{' + str(len(exp_mod)-4) + '}\}|\(.{' + str(len(exp_mod)-2) + '}\)|\[.{' + str(len(exp_mod)-2) + '}\]|\{.{' + str(len(exp_mod)-2) + '}\}|\(.{' + str(len(exp_mod)-8) + '}\)|\[.{' + str(len(exp_mod)-8) + '}\]|\{.{' + str(len(exp_mod)-8) + '}\}'
    if len(re.sub(pattern, '', exp_mod)) > 0:
        print(False)            
    else:
        print(True)
```

Comment: Жесть какая. Лучше уж на чистом Python.

Comment: ответы к вопросам с меткой [tag:инспекция-кода] должны, что-то о коде в вопросе сказать (построчная критика или просто в целом обзор)¶ Если вы просто хотите решение опубликовать, не рассматривая код в вопросе, то есть другой вопрос: [Проверить правильно ли вложены скобки 〈 ( { \[ \] } ) 〉в тексте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587694/23044)