# Проверить правильно ли вложены скобки 〈 ( { [ ] } ) 〉в тексте

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Вот пример, где `скобки 〈 п{р}авильно (вло[ж]ены)〉.`
Вот пример, где `скобки НЕ 〈 пр(авильно вложены〉).`

Comment: Похожий вопрос [Проверка на верное количество скобок \[ { ( ) } \]](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587653/23044)—не дубликат так как он из категории [tag:инспекция-кода] [вот пост, хорошо разницу между Code Review и Stack Overflow вопросами объясняющий](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778)

Comment: Зачем задавать вопрос на который уже есть ответ ?

Comment: @faoxis: потому что вопросы разные (критика кода vs. как реализовать). Посмотрите на принятые ответы у обоих вопросов. Подумайте в чём разница. Прочтите описание метки [инспекция-кода](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info).

Comment: @faoxis: если ваш комментарий был о том зачем я на собственный вопрос ответил, то прочтите справку: [«мы призываем участников отвечать на свои вопросы»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Классическое решение с использованием стэка, который сохраняет
типы (несбалансированных) открывающих скобок:

```
Для каждого символа в тексте
   проверить является ли он открывающей скобкой
       если является, то добавить в стэк тип этой скобки (угловая/круглая/итд)
   если нет, то проверить является ли символ закрывающей скобкой
       если является и последняя добавленная открывающая скобка совпадает,
           то убрать её из стэка (найдена совпавшая пара скобок)
       иначе завершить алгоритм—найдена неправильно вложенная скобка.

Продолжать до конца текста и если стэк пустой, то текст содержит
только правильно вложенные скобки.
```

На Питоне 3:

```
def is_balanced(text, brackets="〈〉()[]{}"):
    opening, closing = brackets[::2], brackets[1::2]
    stack = [] # keep track of opening brackets types
    for character in text:
        if character in opening: # bracket
            stack.append(opening.index(character))
        elif character in closing: # bracket
            if stack and stack[-1] == closing.index(character):
                stack.pop()  # remove the matched pair
            else:
                return False # unbalanced (no corresponding opening bracket) or
                             # unmatched (different type) closing bracket
    return (not stack) # no unbalanced brackets
```

В этом случае тип скобки (фигурная/квадратная/итд) представлен индексом в `opening` списке, содержащим все открывающие скобки. `closing` содержит закрывающие скобки тех же типов на тех же индексах.

Пример:

```
>>> is_balanced('скобки 〈 п{р}авильно (вло[ж]ены)〉')
True
>>> is_balanced('скобки НЕ 〈 пр(авильно вложены〉)')
False
```

Comment: @tr4ngira: `opening` would be wrong. The `character` is from the `closing` list.

Answer (score 2):

Можно примерно так:

```
def is_balanced(text):
    text = "".join(el for el in text if el in "〈({[]})〉")
    
    while text:
        flag = True
        for el in  "〈〉", "()", "{}", "[]":
            if el in text:
                text = text.replace(el, "")
                flag = False
        if flag:
            return False
    return True
```

Убираем все символы кроме скобок. Далее удаляем все пустые скобки, до тех пор пока строка не останется пустой. А если текст не пустой и в нем нету пустых скобок то возвращаем `False`

Comment: Выглядит так, что должно работать. Это квадратичный алгоритм так же как и код, основанный на regex. Классический алгоритм из принятого ответа это линейный алгоритм. Вот [ответ, где сравниваются линейный и квадратичные алгоритмы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710403/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Можно удалять плоские (невложенные) сбалансированные части пока это возможно, а затем проверить остались ли [несбалансированные] скобки в тексте:

```
def is_balanced(text, brackets="〈〉()[]{}"):
    L = list(map(re.escape, brackets))  # make it safe for a regex
    regex = re.compile('|'.join(  # O <-> opening, C <-> closing
        ['{O}[^{B}]*{C}'.format(B=''.join(L),**vars()) for O, C in zip(L[::2], L[1::2])]))
    n = "number of substitutions"
    while n:
        text, n = regex.subn('', text)  # remove non-nested/flat balanced parts
    return set(brackets).isdisjoint(text)  # no [unbalanced] brackets left
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать другой алгоритм через стэк, сложность О(n):

```
s=list(input())
st=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i]=='(' or s[i]=='{' or s[i]=='[':
        st.append(s[i])
        continue
    if (s[i]==')' or s[i]=='}' or s[i]==']') and st:
        if (st[-1]+s[i]=='()') or (st[-1]+s[i]=='{}') or (st[-1]+s[i]=='[]'):
            st.pop()
        else:
            print('no')
            exit()
    else:
        print('no')
        exit()
if st==[]:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: это похоже  не менее общий вариант алгоритма из принятого ответа

Comment: `s/не менее общий/на менее общий/`

Answer (score 0):

Вариант принятого ответа, который работает с граничными условиями (если передать `)(` или пустую последовательность, или если в ходе выполнения функции стек опустеет):

```py
def is_correct_bracket_seq(line: str) -> bool:
    stack = []
    open_brackets = ['(', '{', '[']
    close_brackets = [')', '}', ']']
    if not line:
        return True
    elif line[0] in close_brackets:
        return False
    for character in line:
        if character in open_brackets:
            stack.append(open_brackets.index(character))
        elif character in close_brackets:
            if len(stack) != 0 and stack[-1] == close_brackets.index(character):
                stack.pop()
            else:
                return False
    return len(data) == 0
```

Comment: Это выглядит как менее общий вариант принятого ответа. Для ввода `')('` или `''` ответы совпадают.