# Фильтрация значения 0.0 в генераторе игнорирует False

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Имеется исходный список:

```
array = [9, 0.0, 0, 9, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]
```

Использую генератор

```
aaa = [a for a in array if a is not 0.0 and a is not 0]
```

```
>>> print aaa
[9, 0.0, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 3, 1, 9, 9]
    ^^^                 ^^^ - почему значение 0.0 проигнорировало фильтр?
                              при этом значение 0 отработало правильно.
```

Проверяем:

```
>>> 0.0 is not 0.0 and 0.0 is not 0
False

>>> 0 is not 0.0 and 0 is not 0
False
```

**UPD.**

Данный вопрос возник из задания такого вида

Дано:

```
["a",0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9]
```

Сдвинуть 0.0 и 0 в правую часть списка не меняя порядка цифр, 0.0 преобразуется в 0, ответ:

```
["a","b",None,"c","d",1,False,1,3,[],1,9,{},9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Не стал выкладывать всю задачу, т.к. хочу сам дойти до ответа, а не получать все готовенькое.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Присваивание в Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571490/23044)

Comment: то что после **UPD** в отдельный вопрос(ы) лучше вынести. К примеру, "как сравнить с нулём, чтобы None не совпадал" и/или "как перенести элементы в конец списка  по условию, сохраняя порядок"

Comment: UPD это не вопрос  "хочу сам дойти до ответа, а не получать все готовенькое.", а просто дополнение, чтобы лучше передать, почему используется конструкция вида [a for a in array if a is not 0.0 and a is not 0]

Comment: я понимаю (у вас текущий вопрос "почему is не работает", ответы на него не решат исходную задачу). Вы можете одновременно задать вопрос и ответить на него—[это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (чтобы увидеть альтернативные решения, комментарии на ваше). И/или готовое решение с меткой инспекция-кода опубликовать (если уверены в правильности результата и альтернативные решения не интересуют, но хотите комментарии по любым аспектам кода). Пример вопроса [с меткой](https://goo.gl/ZBABa1) и [без метки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587694/23044)

Answer (score 6):

Дело в том, что `is` проверяет, что сравниваемые величины ссылаются на один объект. Для `float` использование одного и того же объекта для равных объектов не гарантируется. Можно проверить следующим образом:

```
>>> x = 0.0
>>> x is 0.0
False
```

В вашем случае, если интересуют только ненулевые объекты, то проще написать так:

```
>>> array = [9, 0.0, 0, 9, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]
>>> [a for a in array if a]
[9, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 9]
```

Или даже так (как предложил [@vadim vaduxa](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/208915)):

```
>>> filter(bool, array)  # или list(filter(bool, array)) для Python 3
[9, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 9]
```

Для Python 3 нужно явное преобразование к списку, потому что там `filter` работает лениво.

В таком случае отфильтруются все ненулевые объекты.

Во всех этих случаях мы используем тот факт, что `0.0` и `0` отображаются в `False` при приведению к `bool`.

Comment: Добавлю, что даже для достаточно больших int не гарантируется использование тех же объектов для одинаковых чисел. Точного значения сейчас не вспомню, но что-то того же порядка, что и максимальное однобайтовое число. То есть, пока числа измеряются десятками - всё нормально. Но где-то на сотнях is уже перестаёт работать как замена проверки на равенство.

Comment: @Александр В любом случае, полагаться на это свойство целых чисел при написании программ не стоит, так как это больше похоже на детали реализации, чем на спецификацию

Comment: вместо `bool`, можно писать: `filter(None, array)`. Не нужно `list()` добавлять в Питоне 2. (посмотрите на метки вопроса)

Comment: @jfs Да, действительно, привычка. Внесу поправку. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
aaa1 = [a for a in array if not a == 0.0 and not a == 0]

a = filter(bool, array)
aaa2 = list(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ваши ответы, они оказались полезны, нашел 2 варианта решения своего вопроса:

```
 [a for a in array if str(a) not in ['0',  '0.0']]

 [a for a in array if type(a) is bool or a!= 0]
```

Если есть еще способы в одну строчку, буду рад их узнать.

Comment: Таких ужасов как: `str(a) not in ['0',  '0.0']` следует избегать. Если вы хотите убрать нули, но оставить `None`, `""`, `[]`, `{}`, `False`, то можно так прямо и написать: `if x != 0 or x is False`.