# Как повернуть матрицу (двумерный массив) на 90 градусов с помощью zip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, матрицы

Как сделать поворот матрицы в одну строчку без NumPy и циклов?

Например, если исходная матрица:

```
[[1, 2],
[3, 4]]
```

то результирующая должна быть:

```
[[3, 1],
[4, 2]]
```

Comment: Во-первых, это не вопрос. Во-вторых, это можно было оформить как перевод оригинала с вопросом и ответом. В третьих, небось тормозит :)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Matrix Transpose in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это не вопрос.

Comment: @kff следует просто разбить на две части: "как повернуть" (вопрос), "один из способов это сделать, с объяснением" (ответ). Ответ, конечно, в форму для ответа поместить. [Это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Например, как я [здесь сделал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587694/23044)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вполне себе рабочий вариант, если скорость не критична.

Но если есть требования по скорости обработки, то лучше все-таки воспользоваться NumPy.

Сравнение производительности для массива 100x100:

```
In [72]: a = np.random.randint(0, 99, (100, 100))

In [73]: m = a.tolist()

In [74]: a.shape
Out[74]: (100, 100)

In [75]: %timeit tuple(zip(*m[::-1]))
10000 loops, best of 3: 71 µs per loop

In [76]: %timeit np.rot90(a, 3)
The slowest run took 9.64 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.63 µs per loop
```

Сравнение производительности для массива 1000x1000:

```
In [77]: a = np.random.randint(0, 99, (1000, 1000))

In [78]: m = a.tolist()

In [79]: a.shape
Out[79]: (1000, 1000)

In [80]: %timeit tuple(zip(*m[::-1]))
10 loops, best of 3: 32.6 ms per loop

In [81]: %timeit np.rot90(a, 3)
The slowest run took 7.54 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.59 µs per loop
```

Сравнение производительности для массива 10000x10000:

```
In [82]: a = np.random.randint(0, 99, (10000, 10000))

In [83]: m = a.tolist()

In [84]: a.shape
Out[84]: (10000, 10000)

In [85]: %timeit tuple(zip(*m[::-1]))
1 loop, best of 3: 4.43 s per loop

In [86]: %timeit np.rot90(a, 3)
The slowest run took 11.29 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.59 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 14):

​Нашел довольно элегантный способ сделать поворот матрицы в одну строчку без numpy и циклов. В рунете ничего толкового не смог найти, может кому то поможет.
Оригинал здесь:
[Линк на оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421337/rotating-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

```
rotated = zip(*original[::-1]) # Python 2
rotated = tuple(zip(*original[::-1])) # Python 3
```

Как это работает.

```
original = [[1, 2],
            [3, 4]]
```

Сначала работает реверс

```
 >>> original[::-1] 
    [[3, 4], [1, 2]]
```

И далее этот уже обернутый список передаётся функции `zip()`

```
zip([3, 4],
    [1, 2])
#    ^  ^----column 2
#    |-------column 1
```

Надеюсь, кому-то пригодится, а то начинают перебор через встроенные циклы и т.д.

Comment: Если нам нужен полностью изменяемый объект, то, я полагаю, tuple'ы в list'ы можно превратить таким образом: list(map(list, zip(*original[::-1])))

Comment: И для поворота против часовой стрелки: list(map(list, reversed(list(zip(*f)))))