# Поворот треугольников внутри квадратной матрицы

Tags: алгоритм, матрицы

Предложили решить вот такую задачку по матрицам.

> Предлагается квадратная матрица N*N, где N - нечетное число. Требуется "переместить" по часовой стрелке "внутренности" 4 треугольников, образующихся при делении матрицы диагоналями квадрата.

Не могу понять как подойти к задаче, каким алгоритмом руководствоваться.

Comment: Начинайте всегда с самого наивного алгоритма, потом найдете как это сделать лучше.

Comment: Сделайте себе в уме координатную сетку : в центре координата (0,0). Тогда путь перемещений будет : `(x,y)->(y,-x)->(-x,-y)->(-y,x)->(x,y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша задача ничем не отличается от "повернуть квадратную матрицу по часовой стрелке", все эти условия про диагонали и треугольники введены, чтобы запутать вас и лишь маскируют общую картину.

Если вы хотя бы нарисовали на листочке как и что перемещается - вы бы сразу поняли, что задачи одинаковы.

Ну а поворот матрицы по часовой стрелке - это настолько избитая задача, что ищется на счёт раз.

Маленькая подсказка: повернутая на 90 градусов матрица - это матрица в которой поменяны местами x и y.

Есть даже реализации на stackoverflow, посмотрите например начиная отсюда:

- [Поворот матрицы (двумерного массива) на 90 градусов в Python с помощью zip](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/605620/213987)
- [Поворот матрицы на 90° (градусов)](http://redgears.ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-90%C2%B0-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2/)
- [Существует ли элегантный алгоритм для поворота 4×4 матрицы на 90 градусов?](https://toster.ru/q/244378)