# Python функция zip при повороте матрицы

Tags: python

Прошу Вашей помощи, учу питон, пытаюсь разобраться с тем, как работает функция zip в python.

Мне понятно, как работает данная функция в простых примерах типа:

```
first = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
second = [1 ,2, 3, 4]

print(list(zip(first, second)))

[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

Однако, если пример немного усложняется, для меня это превращается в "магию"
Например, при повороте матрицы.

Исходная матрица:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'e', 'g']
['n', 'x', 'y']
```

Пример кода:

```
martix = [['a','b','c'],
          ['d', 'e', 'g'],
          ['n', 'x', 'y']]


matrix_rotate = tuple(zip(*martix[::-1]))

for _ in matrix_rotate:
    print(list(_))
```

Повернутая матрица:

```
['n', 'd', 'a']
['x', 'e', 'b']
['y', 'g', 'c']
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как произошел поворот матрицы? Почему?

Спасибо!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Поворот матрицы (двумерного массива) на 90 градусов в Python с помощью zip](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605620/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-90-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-python-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-zip)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте разобьём строку `matrix_rotate = tuple(zip(*martix[::-1]))` на несколько последовательных действий. Так будет несколько проще понять.
Сначала перевернём матрицу (а для Python - это список списков):

```
matrix_flipped = martix[::-1]
```

Получим список с элементами в обратном порядке:

```
[['n', 'x', 'y'],
['d', 'e', 'g'],
['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Далее, с помощью `*` передадим последовательно элементы списка `matrix_flipped` в качестве аргументов функции `zip`. Две написанные ниже строки в данном конкретном случае эквивалентны:

```
zip(*matrix_flipped)
zip(['n', 'x', 'y'], ['d', 'e', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Наконец, что вернёт нам `zip`? `zip` берёт, и составляет кортежи последовательно из элементов каждого аргумента. Первый возвращённый кортеж будет состоять из первых элементов переданных списков, т.е. `('n', 'd', 'a')`, второй кортеж будет состоять из вторых элементов аргументов, т.е. `('x', 'e', 'b')`. И так, пока элементы в аргументах не закончатся. А когда это произойдёт, `tuple(zip(*matrix[::-1]))` вернёт:

```
(('n', 'd', 'a'),
 ('x', 'e', 'b'),
 ('y', 'g', 'c'))
```

Вот и результат!

И, небольшая заметка. `tuple()` вызывается для того, чтобы представить результат в виде кортежа. Если этого не сделать, то Вы получите итератор вместо полноценного результата. `zip`, на самом деле, не выдаст результат своих действий сразу целиком. Ему лень считать всё сразу, и он возвращает объект (итератор), который вычислит следующий элемент лишь тогда, когда его об этом попросят. С помощью `tuple()` Вы заставляете всё это сделать, и вернуть результат в виде кортежа. Этот факт может звучать сложно для новичка, но пока можно принять как данность, а разобраться позже, уверен, не составит труда.

Answer (score 3):

Давай внимательно посмотрим, что происходит тут:

```
matrix_rotate = tuple(zip(*martix[::-1]))
```

1. Мы итерируем список matrix, состоящий из списков. Причем проходим в обратном порядке (т.к. [::-1]). 
   Мы итерируем в таком порядке:

   ```
   ['n','x','y'],['d','e','g'],['a','b','c']  # Можно проверить самому командой print(*martix[::-1])
   ```

А функция zip объединяет значения этих списков по порядку:

```
['n', 'd', 'a'] # По индексу 0
['x', 'e', 'b'] # По индексу 1
['y', 'g', 'c'] # По индексу 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Этот вопрос был дан на дубликат вопроса и перенесён [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1133921/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-zip).

Существует занимательный факт, что ***функция `zip` эквивалентна операции транспонирования матрицы в математическом смысле***.

Не следует забывать, что `zip` принимает на вход `k` коллекций итерируемых объектов и возвращает итератор. Пример

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i, j in zip(a, b):
     print(i, j)
```

Ответ:

```
10 a
20 b
30 c
40 d
```

**Формальный пример**. Таким образом, имеем матрицу `Amxn`, которая имеем матрицу, у которой есть строки: `c0, c1, c2, ..., cn`. После применения операции `zip`, получим итератор, который вернёт строки `c0, c1, c2, ..., cm` той же матрицы.

*Следует отметить, что в случае, если итерируемые объекты различной длины, выравнивание происходит по наименьшему.*

Немного больше про функцию `zip` можно найти [тут](https://younglinux.info/python/feature/zip), в [официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) или нескольких PEP: [вот](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0201/) и [вот](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0618/).