# Что делает функция zip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, синтаксис

Для чего нужна функция `zip` в python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот вопрос был задан, чтобы указать на занимательный факт, что ***функция `zip` эквивалентна операции транспонирования матрицы в математическом смысле***.

Не следует забывать, что `zip` принимает на вход `k` коллекций итерируемых объектов и возвращает итератор. Пример

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i, j in zip(a, b):
     print(i, j)
```

Ответ:

```
10 a
20 b
30 c
40 d
```

**Формальный пример**. Таким образом, имеем матрицу `Amxn`, которая имеем матрицу, у которой есть строки: `c0, c1, c2, ..., cn`. После применения операции `zip`, получим итератор, который вернёт строки `c0, c1, c2, ..., cm` той же матрицы.

*Следует отметить, что в случае, если итерируемые объекты различной длины, выравнивание происходит по наименьшему.*

Немного больше про функцию `zip` можно найти [тут](https://younglinux.info/python/feature/zip), в [официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) или нескольких PEP: [вот](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0201/) и [вот](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0618/).