# Как на пайтон убрать из строки все скобки и все что в них

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

До: **Жвачка с перцем (уп. 3шт)**

После: **Жвачка с перцем**

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59436/discussion-on-question-by------------).

Answer (score 8):

Если скобки не могут быть вложены, то чтобы убрать скобки и всё что между ними из строки `text`:

```
import re

text = re.sub(r'\([^()]*\)', '', text)
```

Если скобки могут быть вложены:

```
def remove_text_between_parens(text):
    n = 1  # run at least once
    while n:
        text, n = re.subn(r'\([^()]*\)', '', text)  # remove non-nested/flat balanced parts
    return text
```

Пример:

```
>>> remove_text_between_parens("(внутри) снаружи (текст (вложеный))")
' снаружи '
```

См. также:

- [Проверить правильно ли вложены скобки 〈 ( { [ ] } ) 〉в тексте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587694/23044)
- [Remove text between () and [] in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14596884/4279)

Comment: Да это ж [перевод моего ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528373/how-to-remove-all-text-between-the-outer-parentheses-in-a-string).

Comment: Точно нет. Я подобный код публиковал ещё до создания StackOverflow

Comment: Я смотрю код вплоть до комментариев совпадает.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день, для конкретного примера, работает вот это:
Единственное, чего не должно быть - повторяющихся скобок (( или ( text(:

```
#До: Жвачка с перцем (уп. 3шт) После: Жвачка с перцем
#Monkey code
#Работает только тогда когжа есть "( " и ")" в тексте, в одном экземпляре

#> a=input("Enter your string with (): ") 
#>c=list(a) 
#>while ("(" in c)==True:
#>     s1=c.index("(")
#>     while c[s1]!=")":
#>         c.pop(s1)
#>     c.remove(")")
#>     if c[s1-1]==" ": #s1-1 чтобы удалить пробел
#>         c.pop(s1-1)
#>print(''.join(c))

>#**********Простая реализация кода***********#
>#s=input()
>#s = s[:s.index('(')] + s[s.index(')')+1:]
>#print(s)
>#***Попытка избавиться от О(n^2) алгоритма**#
>a=input()
>c=list(a)
>s1=c.index('(')
>while (")" in c):
>    c.pop(s1)
>c="".join(c)
>c.strip(" ")
>print(c)
```

Comment: Если вы уверены, что `()` ровно один раз встречаются в нужном порядке: `s = s[:s.index('(')] + s[s.index(')')+1:]`, где `s = '...(...)...'` 1- что заставило вас написать `("(" in c) == True` вместо `"(" in c`?  2- `c.pop(s1)` это `O(n)` операция , что делает алгоритм `O(n**2)` без необходимости, даже если скобки не вложены.  Посмотрите, [пример почему линейный алгоритм может быть лучше квадратичного](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596513/23044) 3- нет условия удалить пробел (лучше `.strip()` вызвать, если необходимо.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо за подробный разбор моего кода. Все Ваши уточнения и предложения взял на заметку в дальнейшую работу. Ответ по пункту 1. Не знал, что можно писать без True. 2. Не знал про алгоритмы O(n**2) и O(n). Спасибо, теперь буду знать!

Answer (score 0):

Искал функцию, которая удалит из скобок только квадратных **[text]**. По примеру ответа @jfs методом тыка подогнал под необходимый результат (удалить все квадратные скобки и все что в них):

```
text  = re.sub(r'\[[^\]]+\]', '', text)
```

Comment: Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его стоит просто удалить.

Answer (score 0):

А мне так когда-то помогло:

```
import re

s = "Жвачка с перцем (уп. 3шт)"
r = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', s)
print(r)
```

Вывод

```
Жвачка с перцем
```

Comment: 1) приводите код так, чтобы можно было ешго сразу скопировать и вопсроизвести (надо убрать `>>>` и добавить `import`); 2) смотрите следующий вход https://repl.it/repls/WhimsicalOtherComputergames

Comment: @dIm0n Ваша ссылка не взлетела, капчу просит

Comment: У меня всё работает. Просит капчу -- введите. А вообще там вход `Жвачка с перцем (уп.(123) 3шт)`, на котором ваш код выдаёт `Жвачка с перцем  3шт)`

Comment: @dIm0n Всё верно, в вопросе о вложенных скобках и не спрашивается. Мне и на надо было, когда делал.

Comment: *"убрать из строки все скобки и все что в них"* -- а убраны не все скобки и не всё что в них