# Как убрать все символы, заключенные в квадратные скобки?

Tags: python

Допустим, есть строка:

> Какой-то текст бла-бла[источник не указан 33 дня]. Бла-бла текст[128]

Я хочу, чтобы всё, что заключено в квадратные скобки в тексте было удалено, включая скобки. Для этого я использую регулярное выражение, которым заменяю такой формат на пустую строку. Но почему-то регулярка работает таким образом, что она, встречая первый матч, удаляет его и всё, что идёт после него:

```
re.sub('(\[.+\])', '', item.text)
```

Итого получается текст:

> Какой-то текст бла-бла

Как это исправить?

Comment: ленивый квантификатор поможет.  '\[.+?\]'

Comment: re.sub('[.+?]' , '', item.text)

Comment: @JaponDemon да, помогло. Но только квадратные скобки всё равно нужно экранировать :) https://repl.it/repls/FirebrickPeriodicDribbleware

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как на пайтон убрать из строки все скобки и все что в них](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/660142/23044)