# Наложение скобок

Tags: java, алгоритм

Нам даны строки, содержащие скобки 4 видов - круглые (), квадратные [], фигурные {} и угловые <>. Задача в том, чтобы проверить является ли последовательность скобок корректной. Т.е. любая открывающая скобка должна иметь закрывающую того же типа где-то дальше по строке - и кроме того пары скобок не должны пересекаться, хотя они могут быть вложенными:

(a+[b*c] - {d/3})  - здесь квадратные и фигурные скобки вложены в круглые

(a+[b*c) - 17]     - а здесь "область действия" круглых и квадратных пересекается, что некорректно

Нету вообще никаких идей по поводу того, как можно проверить "наложение" скобок. Как это сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587694/177613

Answer (score 5):

Какие тут могут быть идеи кроме как "в лоб" - хранить в стеке открывающие скобки, а на каждую закрывающую доставать последний элемент из стека и проверять на соответствие типу скобки.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная задача на использование стека.

---

Изначально стек пуст, в нем будут хранится открывающиеся скобки.
  Мы итерируемся по строке символов, если текущий символ - открывающаяся скобка, кидаем его в стек, если это закрывающаяся скобка, то смотрим на состояние стека. Если он пуст - последовательность некорректна (на вход дана последовательность вида '())'). 
  Иначе достаем верхушку из стека и сравниваем на соответсвие (т.е. если сверху '(', то сейчас должна быть ')' и т.д.), если не соответствует - последовательность некорректна (последовательность вида '{]').

---

После проверки всех символов строки смотрим на состояние стека. Если он не пуст - последовательность некорректна (к примеру, '((()').

Если до сих пор не определено, что последовательно некорректна, то мы можем утверждать, что она корректна.

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях меня поправили, так что:
ПРИМЕР НЕВЕРНОГО АЛГОРИТМА))

Можно хранить только кол-во скобок и код последней открытой.
`Например, пусть A [1] - кол-во квадратных открытых - кол-во квадратных закрытых (по умолчанию = 0)`
`A [2] - то же самое для круглых`
`A [3] - для фигурных.`
`И пусть B = 0 - код последней открытой скобки (напр. для круглой B = 2)`

Читаем посимвольно текст

`Если мы встречаем открытую скобку, то A[i]++,`

закрытую - 
`1) A[i]-- и`
`2) если A[i] меньше нуля, то сразу неверно расставлены`
`3) если закрытая скобка не соответствует B и B!=0, то неверно`

`В итоге, если все A[i]==0, то верно.`

Алгоритм придуман только что, поэтому не тестился.

Comment: Недостаточно знать только какая последняя открыта. Например `( [ { } ) ]` явная ошибка расстановки круглых и квадратных скобок, но после того как вы проверите фигурные скобки вы уже не сможете узнать какая была открыта до этого и не сможете проверить правильность расстановки. Хотя по количеству все совпадет

Comment: Да, согласен. Алгоритм - г****. Значит только стек и индекс ожидаемой закрывающей скобки, как и было сказано выше.