# Вывод всех правильно-вложенных скобочных выражений без повторений

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Вечер добрый.Такой вопрос, программа должна выводить все скобочные выражения без повторений.
На ввод идут 3 числа: 
первое обозначает количество пар скобок ()
второе количество пар скобок []
третье количество пар скобок {}

и на вывод должен вывести все варианты правильной расстановки этих скобок (т.е

```
[({})]
{()[]}
{()}[]
{[()]}
{[]()}
{[]}()
{}([])
{}()[]
```

, но не 
`{][()}`  )

```
def variants(iterable, r=None):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(n))
    cycles = list(range(n, n-r, -1))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return


def permutations(count_round, count_square, count_braces):
    create_round = lambda s: '(%s)' % s
    create_square = lambda s: '[%s]' % s
    create_braces = lambda s: '{%s}' % s
    result = set()
    for lf in variants(((create_round,) * count_round) +
                        ((create_square,) * count_square) +
                        ((create_braces,) * count_braces)):
        s = ''
        for f in lf:
            s = f(s)
        result.add(s)
    return result


count_round = int(input()) #()
count_square = int(input()) #[]
count_braces = int(input()) #{}
print('\n'.join(permutations(count_round, count_square, count_braces)))
```

так он выводит только:

```
([{}])
[{()}]
{([])}
({[]})
{[()]}
[({})]
```

но не выводит подобные скобки:

```
{[]()}
{[]}()
{}([])
{}()[]
{()[]}
{()}[]
```

Comment: Что по вашему "правильная расстановка"? Большую часть из  вашей "правильной расстановки" питон посчитает неправильной.

Comment: @Alban, ()[]{}
(){[]}
(){}[]
[({})]
[(){}]
[()]{}
[{()}]
[{}()]
[{}]()
[]({})
[](){}
[]{()}
[]{}()

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Проверить правильно ли вложены скобки 〈 ( { [ \] } ) 〉в тексте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587694/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BRACKET_MAP = {
  '[': ']',
  '(': ')',
  '{': '}'
}

def brackets(Q,W,E, stack=[], opened=[]):
  if (Q,W,E) == (0,0,0) and not opened:
    yield ''.join(stack)
  else:
    if opened:
      yield from brackets(Q,W,E, stack + [BRACKET_MAP[opened[0]]], opened[1:])
    if Q:
      yield from brackets(Q-1, W, E, stack + ['('], ['('] + opened)
    if W:
      yield from  brackets(Q, W-1, E, stack + ['['], ['['] + opened)
    if E:
      yield from  brackets(Q, W, E-1, stack + ['{'], ['{'] + opened)

Q = int(input())
W = int(input())
E = int(input())
if Q >= 0 and W >= 0 and E >= 0:
    for combo in brackets(Q,W,E):
      print(combo)
else:
    print("ERROR")
```

Comment: спасибо большое, а как можно осуществить проверку на повторение одних и тех же строк? например:                                                            {}{}
{{}}
{}{}
{{}}    3 и 4 это повтор двух первых

Comment: внес изменение в решение, убрал циклы заменив их на if

Comment: я уже тоже попробовал поменять for на if и получилось, спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете это оптимизировать:

```
import itertools


def permutations(count_round, count_square, count_braces):
    create_round = lambda s: '(%s)' % s
    create_square = lambda s: '[%s]' % s
    create_braces = lambda s: '{%s}' % s
    result = set()
    for lf in itertools.permutations(((create_round,) * count_round) +
                                     ((create_square,) * count_square) +
                                     ((create_braces,) * count_braces)):
        s = ''
        for f in lf:
          s = f(s)
        result.add(s)
    return result


count_round = 2 #()
count_square = 2 #[]
count_braces = 2 #{}
print('\n'.join(permutations(count_round, count_square, count_braces)))
```