# Циклы. Не могу понять в чем ошибка

Tags: python

#1. Дана строка, представляющая из себя некоторое выражение. Проверить корректность использования скобок в заданном выражении:
#a. количество открывающихся скобок каждого вида должно соответствовать количеству закрывающихся скобок этого же вида;
#b. порядок следования открывающихся и закрывающихся скобок должен быть верным.

```
l = "aaa(bc{def}(ggg(hh))"
a = []
braces = {']': '[', '}': '{', ')': '('}
for i in l:
    if i in braces.values():
        a.append(i)
        print(a)
    elif i in braces.keys():
        if len(a) == 0 or braces[i] != a.pop():
            print("Выражение неправильное")
            break
 else:
      if len(a) > 0:
          print("Выражение неправильное")
      else:
          print("Выражение правильное")
```

не могу понять почему в выводе ошибка:

```
['('] ['(', '{'] ['(', '('] ['(', '(', '(']
```

Это вывод. Не могу понять почему не добавляет фигурную скобку

Comment: ['(']
['(', '{']
['(', '(']
['(', '(', '(']
Выражение неправильное
Это вывод. Не могу понять почему не добавляет фигурную скобку

Comment: Форматирование поправьте

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверить правильно ли вложены скобки 〈 ( { \[ \] } ) 〉в тексте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587694/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: @DanisПодозреваю, что ваше форматирование неверное, т.к. последний блок должен выполняться единожды после цикла.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но форматирование не помогло. Это задание с Udemy так делал преподаватель у нее по видео все работало , а у меня нет .Вот и стало интересно почему

Comment: Запустила ее код тоже не работает

Comment: Форматирование по-прежнему негодное. Если его исправить, код как-то работает, справедливо выводя `['(', '(', '('] Выражение неправильное`. Фигурная скобка из стека уже удалена

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного подрихтовал вашу попытку:

```
l = "aaa(bc{def}(ggg(hh))"
a = []
braces = {']': '[', '}': '{', ')': '('} 
for i in l:
    print(a)
    if i in braces.values():
        a.append(i)
        print(a)
    elif i in braces.keys():
        if  len(a)>0 and braces[i] == a[-1]:
            a.pop()
        else:
            print("Выражение неправильное")
            break   
if len(a) > 0:
    print("Выражение неправильное")
else:
    print("Выражение правильное")
```

Результат:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
['(']
['(']
['(']
['(']
['(', '{']
['(', '{']
['(', '{']
['(', '{']
['(', '{']
['(']
['(', '(']
['(', '(']
['(', '(']
['(', '(']
['(', '(']
['(', '(', '(']
['(', '(', '(']
['(', '(', '(']
['(', '(', '(']
['(', '(']
Выражение неправильное
```

Если на вход подать

```
l = "aaa(bc{def}(ggg(hh)))"
```

на выходе будет

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
['(']
['(']
['(']
['(']
['(', '{']
['(', '{']
['(', '{']
['(', '{']
['(', '{']
['(']
['(', '(']
['(', '(']
['(', '(']
['(', '(']
['(', '(']
['(', '(', '(']
['(', '(', '(']
['(', '(', '(']
['(', '(', '(']
['(', '(']
['(']
Выражение правильное
```

Там еще возможны некоторые особые ситуации, но до их рассмотрения, я так понимаю, вы еще не дошли. Оставляю удовольствие их найти и исправить - вам.

Comment: Огромное  спасибо passant, вы мне очень помогли.  Я только учусь и в свои 40+ уже тяжеловаты некоторые моменты, но я не сдаюсь))) нет ничего  не возможного, главное  иметь желание)

Comment: Вам, как новичку на сайте, подскажу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers И желаю удачи в учебе. У меня бывали ученики и постарше, так что все у вас получиться ;-)

Answer (score -1):

l должен быть списком чтобы фор работал а он просто строка.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Вы неправы - фор работает с последовательностями (sequence), а строка является последовательностью `A for loop is used for iterating over a sequence (that is either a list, a tuple, a dictionary, a set, or a string)`