# Как улучшить вложенные циклы в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, инспекция-кода, условия

Доброго дня.
С питоном дружу совсем недавно. И ввязался в парсинг сайта. У сайта есть таблица несколько колонок и несколько строк. Нужно обойти все строки и колонки и вывести их как надо. И не придумал ничего лучшего кроме как вложенного цикла. Но чую душой и сердцем что в таком замечательном языке как Python можно сделать это куда более красивее. Подскажите пожалуйста, ну или хотя бы намекните, в какую сторону думать? Я из каждой строки исходных данных получаю то что мне надо и потом уже буду их обрабатывать как нужно.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def startGrab():
    url = 'http:/site.net'

    try:
        page = requests.get(url)
    except:
        print(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")

    for row in soup.find_all("tr", {"class" : "belowHeader"}):
        i = 0
        x = 0
        for row2 in row.find_all("td", {"class" : "tdteamname2"}):
            if i==0:
                team1 = row2.get_text()
            else:
                team2 = row2.get_text()
            i += 1
        for row3 in row.find_all("td", {"class" : "tdpercentmw1"}):
            if x == 0:
                coef1 = row3.get_text()
            elif x == 1:
                coef2 = row3.get_text()
            else:
                coef3 = row3.get_text()
            x += 1
        print(team1+" "+team2+" "+coef1+" "+coef2+" "+coef3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startGrab()
```

Comment: Можете указать пример страницы, которую вы хотите парсить?

Comment: Доступа к сайту извне нету.  Могу сказать что таблица класса "belowHeader". В ней 2 ячейки класса "tdteamname2" и потом три ячейки класса "tdpercentmw1". Текст из ячеек в приведенном примере выдёргивается нормально. Но хочется как то красивее сделать код.

Comment: ну можно например выложить на какой-нибудь файлообменник пример вашего HTML файла

Comment: Да конечно, вот кусок таблицы: https://codeshare.io/G87W4a

Comment: для создания хорошего ответа в метке [tag:инспекция-кода], может пригодится [ответ @200_success♦ с codereview.SE](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/913/6143)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Построчные комментарии к коду:</sup>

### Поиск элемента по имени элемента и его класса

Вместо:

```
soup.find_all("tr", {"class" : "belowHeader"})
```

Можно просто:

```
soup.find_all("tr", "belowHeader")
```

### Используйте enumerate() чтобы индекс цикла получить

Вместо:

```
i = 0
for td in tr.find_all('td', 'tdteamname2'):
    ...
    i += 1
```

Следует писать:

```
for i, td in enumerate(row.find_all('td', 'tdteamname2')):
    ...
```

### Можно использовать имена элементов  tr, td вместо row, row1, row2

### Используйте явные коллекции вместо имён с номерами

Вместо:

```
x = 0
for row3 in row.find_all("td", {"class" : "tdpercentmw1"}):
    if x == 0:
        coef1 = row3.get_text()
    elif x == 1:
        coef2 = row3.get_text()
    else:
        coef3 = row3.get_text()
    x += 1
```

Используйте:

```
coef = [td.get_text() for td in tr.find_all('td', 'tdpercentmw1')]
```

Аналогично для `team`:

```
team = [td.get_text() for td in tr.find_all('td', 'tdteamname2')]
```

#### [опционально] Можно использовать `print(*коллекция)`

Вместо:

```
print(team1+" "+team2+" "+coef1+" "+coef2+" "+coef3)
```

Можно написать:

```
print(*team, *coef)
```

### Передавайте кодировку, если она известна из http-заголовков

Вместо:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
```

Можно писать:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib", from_encoding=page.encoding)
```

#### [опционально] используйте stdlib если нет причин к обратному

К примеру, если c разметкой особых проблем нет, то можно `'html.parser'` вместо `'html5lib'` парсер использовать.

Или если в вашем случае достаточно возможностей, `urlopen()`, то можно не использовать `requests`—это может быть менее безопасно (`requests` чаще обновляется), но и баги более стабильные.

#### [Не используйте чистый (bare) `except:`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587707/23044)

В вашем случае, можно позволить скрипту просто умереть, так как если страница не загружена, то ему нечего делать. Можно перехватить ожидаемые типы исключений и завершиться с информативным сообщением об ошибке (по опыту использования ясно какие типы ожидать, например, можно с `OSError` начать). Слишком много не ловите, чтобы баги в коде не скрывать.

Чтобы в консоль не мусорить, [можно `sys.excepthook` свой установить](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook).

#### [Используйте shebang `#!` для исполняемых модулей](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31954823/4279)

Если собрать весь код в одно место:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifoulSoup  # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://example.com'), 'html.parser')
for tr in soup.find_all('tr', 'belowHeader'):
    team = (td.get_text() for td in tr.find_all('td', 'tdteamname2'))
    coef = (td.get_text() for td in tr.find_all('td', 'tdpercentmw1'))
    print(*team, *coef)
```

Если проблемы с кодировкой возникнут, то можно [`response.headers.get_content_charset(default)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14592894/4279) передать в качестве `from_encoding` параметра.

[Если проблемы с быстродействием распознавания html](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#improving-performance) (не загрузки), то можно попробовать `'lxml'` парсер, вместо `'html.parser'`.

Вложенные циклы выглядят оправдано здесь. Если нет особых причин от них избавляться, можно их оставить.