# Ошибка: TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Когда компилирую этот код (в Sublime Text):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_id = 12
url = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/'
r = requests.get(url)
with open('news.html', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.content.decode('cp1251'))

with open('news.html') as input_file:
    text = input_file.read()

result = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
news_list = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'newsList newsList_main'})
items = news_list.find('div', {'class' : 'item item_link'})
for item in items:
    name_new = item.find('div', {'class' : 'title'}).find('a').text
    result.append(name_new)
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pylab3_2.py", line 18, in <module>
    name_new = item.find('div', {'class' : 'title'}).find('a').text
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: в сторону: посмотрите [какие рекомендации могут улучшить ваш код](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/590491/23044)

Comment: @jfs о, спасибо, так намного удобнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена, вместо `items = news_list.find('div', {'class' : 'item item_link'})`, нужно было `items = news_list.find_all('div', {'class' : 'item item_link'})`