# Ошибка TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

Добрый день. Никак не могу понять почему вылетает ошибка:

> File "D:/Python/Parser/pars.py", line 41, in startGrab
>       cursor.execute(query, tmatch) TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Вот код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import psycopg2

conStr = "postgresql://parse:parse@localhost:5432/pars"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conStr)
cursor = conn.cursor()

def startGrab():
    base_url = 'http://localhost/way'

    url = base_url
    try:
        page = requests.get(url)
    except:
        print(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")


    for row in soup.find_all("tr", {"class" : "belowHeader"}):
        i = 0
        x = 0
        for row2 in row.find_all("td", {"class" : "tdteamname2"}):
            if i==0:
                team1 = row2.get_text()
            else:
                team2 = row2.get_text()
            i += 1
        for row3 in row.find_all("td", {"class" : "tdpercentmw1"}):
            if x == 0:
                coef1 = row3.get_text()
            elif x == 1:
                coef2 = row3.get_text()
            else:
                coef3 = row3.get_text()
            x += 1
        tmatch = team1+" "+team2+" "+coef1+" "+coef2+" "+coef3
        print(tmatch)
        query = "INSERT INTO matches(text) VALUES (%s);"
        cursor.execute(query, tmatch)
        conn.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startGrab()
```

Comment: не имеет отношения к вопросу: у вас куча (мелких) погрешностей в коде, которые можно легко улучшить. Если вас это интересует, то когда добьетесь, чтобы код работал именно так как вам нужно, то задайте вопрос о том как сделать уже рабочий код более идиоматичным, используя метку [tag:инспекция-кода]. Вот [пример вопроса, чтобы было ясно, что можно ожидать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587653/23044)

Comment: по поводу погрешностей в коде которые можно улучшить я задавал тут уже вопрос, но никто так и не откликнулся)) Вот если интересно: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590491/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-python

Comment: это близко и если текущий код возвращает именно то что нужно и вы понимаете разницу [между обычным вопросом и code review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778), то можете добавить метку к тому вашему вопросу [tag:инспекция-кода]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `excecute` вторым параметром ждет `tuple`. Попробуйте написать так:

```
cursor.execute(query, (tmatch,))
```

В документации, кстати, об этом говорится: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: Не помогло, та же самая ошибка:File "D:/Python/Parser/pars.py", line 41, in startGrab
    cursor.execute(query, (tmatch))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @LeReve, а так: cursor.execute(query, tuple(tmatch))

Comment: @LeReve, вы точно не забыли **запятую** в прошлом варианте: **(tmatch,)**? Просто в тексте ошибки, который вы привели запятой нет.

Comment: @Klym: `(t,)` и `tuple(t)` это разные вещи. Для ясности, можно `[t]` попробовать.

Comment: @jfs, я понимаю что разные, просто вариант с `(t, )` должен работать.

Comment: Кажется понятно, что ничего не понятно. Сделал пробную запись из документации >>> SQL = "INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES (%s);" 
>>> data = ("O'Reilly", )
>>> cur.execute(SQL, data) . Все прошло успешно. Значит беда не с запросом, а с tmatch. При отладке показывал что тип string

Comment: @Klym: я знаю, что `(t,)` работает. Если вы понимаете разницу, то зачем советуете вариант с `tuple(tmatch)`, который не будет работать?

Comment: @jfs, перебираю все возможные варианты.

Comment: @Klym В общем я заменил данные из примера на свои и все заработало. Хотя не вижу в чем отличие. Спасибо.