# Как записать user и id в отдельный файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Здравствуйте. Я пишу бота для *Telegram*, но не как не могу разобраться с одним вопросом: как сделать, чтобы бот записывал `user` и `id` пользователя в отдельный файл. Как можно это реализовать?

- **Платформа**: Telegram
- **Библиотека**: [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)
- **Язык**: Python v3.5

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: вопрос следовало бы переформулировать, так как его суть в _"как в питоне записать что-то в файл"_ и телеграм вместе с ботами тут ни при чём совершенно

Answer (score 3):

Примерно вот так:

```
# Отправляем имя пользователя и его id
def file_user_id(user, uid):
    # Открываем файл для записи
    file = open(str(uid)+'.txt', 'w')
    # Записываем
    file.write("User: {}, id: {}\n".format(user, uid))
    # Закрываем файл
    file.close()
```

Можно отправлять за место `w` другие параметры:

- `r` - открытие на чтение (является значением по умолчанию).
- `w`   открытие на запись, содержимое файла удаляется, если файла не существует, создается новый.
- `x` - открытие на запись, если файла не существует, иначе исключение.
- `a` - открытие на дозапись, информация добавляется в конец файла.
- `b` - открытие в двоичном режиме.
- `t` - открытие в текстовом режиме (является значением по умолчанию).
- `+` - открытие на чтение и запись

---

Но для таких целей лучше использовать БД, допустим: `PostgreSQL`, `MySQL` или `SQLite` - Я бы посоветовал вам использовать `SQLite` её **плюсы:**

- Вся база хранится в 1 файле
- Не требует отдельный сервер где бы крутилась база

**минусы:**

- Это думаю понятно из плюсов, она значительно медленнее других реляционных БД, но это не особо критично при небольшом количестве данный

**Пример для SQLite**:

```
import sqlite3

# Отправляем id пользователя и имя
def add_user(user_id: int, user_name: str):

    # Подключаемся к SQLite
    conn = sqlite3.connect('user.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    # Обработка SQL исключений
    try:
        # Выполняем SQL запрос
        c.execute("INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_name) VALUES (?, ?);", (user_id, user_name))
    except sqlite3.DatabaseError as error:
        # В случаи ошибки
        print("Error:", error)

    # Завершаем транзикцию
    conn.commit()
    # Закрываем соединение
    conn.close()

# Добавляем пользователя Test c id 1
add_user(1, "Test")
```

Модель таблицы для SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE "users"
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    user_name TEXT
);
-- Добавил ключ на уникальность для поля user_id
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_name_user_id_uindex ON "users" (user_id);
-- Добавил ключ для поля user_id
CREATE INDEX table_name_user_name_index ON "users"(user_name);
```

---

Но если вы хотите писать в файл то лучше всего использовать отдельный файл для каждого пользователя.

Я бы предложил такую структуру:

```
user/ <-- Каталог с файлами 
    id1.json <-- Файл пользователя 1 (1 - это id пользователя)
    id2.json 
    id3.json
    id4.json
```

В файле `id1.json` хранится информация о пользователе в формате `json`:

```
 {
     "id": 1,
     "user": "user1"
 }
```

Ну и немного модифицировать код:

```
import json    

# Отправляем имя пользователя и его id
def add_user(uid, user):
    # Открываем файл для записи
    file = open('id{}.json'.format(uid), 'w')
    # Создаем json строку 
    json_str = json.dumps({'user': user, 'id': uid})
    # Записываем наш json
    file.write(json_str)
    # Закрываем файл
    file.close()

# Добавляем пользователя Test c id 1
add_user(1, "Test")
```

И еще как вариант для `.ini` (все равно написал):

```
import configparser

def add_user(uid, user):
    config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    config['USERS'] = {'user': user, 'id': uid}
    config.write(open('user/id{}.ini'.format(uid), 'w'))

add_user(1, "Test")
```

Comment: У вас в коде много стилистических погрешностей. Если хотите улучшить код (если вы уверены что он работает) и готовы любые замечания о коде услышать, то задайте вопрос с меткой [tag:инспекция-кода] Описание метки прочтите, чтобы узнать чем такие вопросы от обычных Stack Overflow вопросов отличаются.

Comment: @jfs вообще код тестил на Python v3 (и он даже работаеееееет) но вы правы, стиль написания кода разный да и есть проблемы в ответе, но старался дать как можно более развернутый ответ.

Comment: работоспособность это требование для вопросов с меткой [инспекция-кода]. Вот [пара](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587653/23044) [примеров](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/590491/23044).

Comment: @jfs единственное я немного не понимаю к чему это все? В плане Матвей Половский не как не реагирует на ответ да и явно больше не зайдет на ру стак. Да все 4 примера из ответа рабочие xD

Comment: комментарии по коду для вас. Простые вещи, которые могут сделать ваш будущий код более идиоматичным.

Comment: Кстати, (напомнила дискуссия с другим участником) ваш ответ не только и не столько для автора вопроса, а для людей с похожей проблемой (на большом Stack Overflow 10-20 раз больше посетителей из веб-поисковиков, чем других участников—автор вопроса может не быть основной аудиторией для ответа). Ещё:  если правка намерение автора не изменяет, то (так как вы детально с ним знакомы) вы можете подредактироаать вопрос, чтобы он большую общность имел, чтобы легче через Гугл найти для людей с похожей проблемой и ближе к вашему ответу, чтобы более полезным был для будущих посетителей.

Answer (score -4):

```
import json


def file_user_id(user, id):
  with open("{}.txt".format(id), "w") as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(dict(user=user, id=id)))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, давайте более развернутые ответы